# get an permission denied error while trying to deploy charts with helmfile

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helmfile

I have created my helmfile and trying to deploy my charts in k8s. But when i try to execute command apply or sync i see permission denied error. Can't understand why this error appears. Here is my helmfile.

```
releases:
- name: ad-service
  chart: charts/core
  values: 
    - values/ad-service.yaml

- name: cart-service
  chart: charts/core
  values: 
    - values/cart-service.yaml

- name: checkout-service
  chart: charts/core
  values: 
    - values/checkout-service.yaml

- name: core-service
  chart: charts/core
  values: 
    - values/core-service.yaml

- name: currency-service
  chart: charts/core
  values: 
    - values/currency-service.yaml

- name: email-service
  chart: charts/core
  values: 
    - values/email-service.yaml

- name: payment-service
  chart: charts/core
  values: 
    - values/payment-service.yaml     

- name: product-catalog
  chart: charts/core
  values: 
    - values/product-catalog.yaml                  

- name: rec-service
  chart: charts/core
  values: 
    - values/rec-service.yaml

- name: redis
  chart: charts/redis
  values: 
    - values/redis.yaml  

- name: shipping-service
  chart: charts/core
  values: 
    - values/shipping-service.yaml
```

I've installed helmfile using snap, so my executing command looks like this:

```
helmfile-snap.helmfile sync
```

And i have encountered this error:

```
in ./helmfile.yaml: open helmfile.yaml: permission denied
```

I was trying to find solution in google but did not see topic related to my issue. Can't understand where is permission issue comes from and why =/

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include the `helmfile.yaml` and the `helmfile sync` output in plain text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wget -O helmfile_linux_amd64 https://github.com/roboll/helmfile/releases/download/v0.135.0/helmfile_linux_amd64
chmod +x helmfile_linux_amd64
sudo mv helmfile_linux_amd64 ../../usr/local/bin/helmfile
helmfile sync
```

fixed. Don't know what was wrong with snap helmfile but i choose snap version at first because it installs in fewer steps :D

Comment: github.com/roboll/helmfile is now deprecated. They have moved to https://github.com/helmfile/helmfile